# UINavigationController hides part of my view

Tags: xcode, uinavigationcontroller, storyboard, xib, nib

I use storyboard, but want to load viewcontroller from xib file.
In storyboard I remove view.
Call to open viewcontroller:

```
- (void)SettingsButtonClick:(id)sender
{    
    CopyViewController* vc;    
    vc = [[CopyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"CopyViewController" bundle:nil];    
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];    
}
```

But navigationcontroller hides part of my view. How can I arrange my View to start its frame below navigationcontroller?

self.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 200, 100, 200); in viewDidLoad doesn't help me :-(

Answer (score 0):

I have found solution

```
self.edgesForExtendedLayout = UIRectEdgeNone;
```